# How to make teamcity's svn checkout more verbose?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a very large svn external containing about 30,000 500k files.  This checkout can take a long time and we would like to see the progress in the TeamCity logs as it happens.

Is there a way to use a more verbose logging when doing the svn checkout than just....

> [19:26:00]: Updating sources: Agent side checkout...
>
> [19:26:00]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
>
> [19:26:00]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] Cleaning /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/937995fe3d15f1e7
>
> [19:26:00]: [Updating sources: Agent side checkout...] VCS Root: guru 6 trunk with externals
>
> [19:26:00]: [VCS Root: guru 6 trunk with externals] revision: 6521_2010/04/27 19:25:58-0500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to make agent-side checkout more verbose.
If you'd use server-side checkout, the checkout progress would be visible, because TeamCity tracks the data sent from the server to build agent and shows how much data have been transferred.
Please feel free to post feature request to Teamcity tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/TW

Answer (score 1):

I've got a very similar problem. If you're on windows, one thing you can do is to use Procmon from sysinternals. You can then see what your box is doing internally. It isn't ideal - but it can at least give you some comfort that TeamCity/the build is progressing.